# laravel 4 HAML file + php var

Tags: php, laravel, haml

how i can declare php variable in HAML file? 
For example I want to produce this:

```
<?php $var = 'test'; ?>
.label {{$var}}
```

I get this error: Undefined variable: var

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in the following way

```
{{--*/ $var = 'test' /*--}}
{{ $var }}
```

Blade comments get translated in the format below.

```
<?php /*COMMENT*/ ?>
```

Thus, the above variable assignment gets translated to the following PHP code.

```
<?php /**/ $var = 'test' /**/ ?>
```

for more details you can follow the below link http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/256/assigning-a-variable-in-a-blade-template